# WCF Service Cannot Login To Remote Database

Tags: .net, wcf, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a WCF service which is hosted in a Windows Service. This Windows service is set to run as LocalSystem. This WCF attempts to login to a remote SQL Server 2008 Express database but the login fails.

The exception error states:

> Cannot open database \"{database name}\" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '{domain name}\{machine name}$'.

I've replaced the database, domain and machine names with tags but you get the idea.

Any idea how I solve this? I thought of adding this user to SQL Server logins but I can't find this user in its properties.

Comment: Show us your connection string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new user account on the sql server, and then impersonating that account from your windows service.

The WindowsIdentity class has many constructors which you can use to create a WindowsIdentity of the user you expect SQL server to allow to login (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e599ywa6.aspx).

Have you tried to change the user of the thread to one recognized by the SQL server as a valid user by using the WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method?

I believe you would put the code to impersonate the user in the service class that is being hosted by the windows service, not in the client code accessing the service.

For details and an example, See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

Store the login information in an encrypted app config file. Under the service project create an app.config file. In that file add a section for the sensitive information (in plain text initially), and once saved ecnrypt the file.

Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=VS.100).aspx
and a walk-through here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

Comment: That would mean needing to store the username and password somewhere. What would be the best solution to that?

Comment: Amended answer to include how to store credentials

Comment: Many thanks, this was a great solution and is now implemented. Thank you to everyone else who contributed too.

Answer (score 1):

The message

`'The login failed. Login failed for user '{domain name}{machine name}$'`

means that your service is attempting to connect to the database using the NETWORK SERVICE account of the machine that it is running on.

If you create a service acccount on your domain, change the service to 'run as' this user, and grant the service account access to your database, this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a custom SQL Server login for this program?  That way it won't matter who you run the service as, you will get consistent results.

Comment: From what I can tell SQL Server 2008 always requires Windows Authentication even if a further SQL login is required.

Comment: That's not right.  From SQL Server Management Studio you can right-click the server, choose Properties, click the 'Security' tab, and under 'Server authentication' choose 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode'